# XAML C# + Unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a large amount of code in C++ (unmanaged), and I'd like to take advantage of the new fluent design features in the latest Windows 10 WPF/XAML. I found a very old sample for Windows 8.1 which shows a C# XAML page being driven by a C++ library, however, both of these are Universal Windows Platform (UWP) projects.

As far as I can tell it is not possible to reference a non-UWP library from a UWP project. The alternative, then, is to use the slightly older WPF components to host XAML controls using functions that allow you to load and render XAML pages (created in Blend, for example), but I've not been able to find a working example of this particular configuration.

Any thoughts or ideas about how to attack this issue will be appreciated, if any of you have figured out how to bridge C# WPF + XAML and unmanaged C++ projects, please let me know!

Comment: Are the C++ libraries just business layer libs, or are you talking forms and visual components you want to host in WPF

Comment: Fluent Design is UWP/Windows 10 only. While UWP uses XAML, it's unrelated to XAML used in WPF. As such, if you want Fluent Design, you cannot use WPF. If you want to incorporate C++ code into your UWP app, use C++/WinRT (or C++/CX).